# El Capitan: Undefined symbol "start" whenever I compile a C program

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang

I recently installed OS X El Capitan, and after I installed it I've been having a problem with my C linker. Whenever I try to compile any program, it says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This happens whether I use Clang installed from the Xcode developer tools, Clang installed from Homebrew, or GCC installed from Homebrew. It only started happening right after I installed El Capitan.

Comment: Can you include the command line you're using to compile your application?

Comment: You mean the command? I'm just using `gcc program.c` or `clang program.c`. But it also fails when I run other programs that need to compile C files (Haskell's Cabal has to compile C files and it fails the same way).

Comment: Have you tried re-installing xcode-7.0.1 - `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: @alvits Yes I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issue.
After I upgraded my macpro to OS X El Capitan, I became unable to compile my program with GNU gcc installed from Macport. It shows same error message. However clang worked fine in my case.

I searched web and found this:
[Undefined symbol "start" while linking D program through LD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996468/undefined-symbol-start-while-linking-d-program-through-ld)
It says add -lcrt1.o in gcc option. 
I tried it and it did fix the problem, so you may try this one.

but I found more complete fix (below), so please try this one too.

In my case, problem was that I had two versions of ld:  /usr/bin/ld and /opt/local/bin/ld. Somehow clang works fine with both versions of ld, but GNU gcc works well only with /usr/bin/ld.

So I changed PATH variable to tell GNU gcc to use /usr/bin/ld, then problem was fixed.